# Хитрая Html табличка

Tags: html

Почему такая табличка не хочет рендериться?
Суть в том, чтобы в первом столбце было 2 строки, а во втором 3.

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="3">1-1</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">2-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="3">1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">2-3</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. http://jsfiddle.net/t9pWW/42/

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="3">1-1</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">2-1</td>
    </tr><tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="3">1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">2-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```